# WebGL Game won't respond to keyboard input. It works perfectly in Unity. How can I make it work in browser?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, unity-webgl

I used a game template and tried to build it for WebGL. Everything works fine until the game opens in browser. Firstly in showed a blue screen but I managed to work around that by editing some configs. Then I added the open scene from the game. However the game character doesn't do anything if I press the arrows keys.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers force you to click on the game before it will handle keyboard input.

Comment: I tried to click on the game however it didn't work.